# Порядок наложения текстур влияет на работу alpha-канала. Как это обойти?

Tags: glut, mingw, c++, opengl

Здравствуйте. Дело обстоит так: я генерирую текстуру с альфа-каналом и накладываю её на все плоскости куба. Проблема заключается в том, что через некоторые абсолютно прозрачные(`alpha channel=0`) области на плоскостях куба не видно других других плоскостей. Методом кручения куба :) понял, что это зависит от порядка наложения текстур на грани в функции `display()`. Например, если смотреть через последнюю по порядку наложения текстуру, то сквозь неё видны все остальные грани, а если смотреть на куб через первую по порядку наложения, то остальные грани не видны.

Мне бы очень хотелось, чтобы через каждую грань куба просматривались остальные, но как это сделать я не знаю. Код большой в нем есть мусор (ссылка внизу). Может быть скриншоты помогут.

[image]

[image]

Спасибо за ваше внимание и помощь.

[Код Dynamic Cube](http://pastie.org/4572691).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, дело в том, что в зависимости от порядка отрисовки задние грани у Вас отбрасываются, потому что не проходят тест глубины, а если бы тест глубины был выключен, они рисовались бы поверх передних, что тоже не является корректным поведением.

В общем случае без сортировки полупрозрачных граней по глубине не обойтись. Сначала нужно рисовать самые дальние, потом самые ближние. Со включенным тестом глубины и блендингом, разумеется. Есть ещё один продвинутый способ - `Depth peeling`. Если ничего не путаю, это когда сцену рисуют целиком (не сортируя треугольники как таковые), но несколько раз с разными плоскостями отсечения по глубине, потом послойно отображают. Качество зависит от количества проходов.

Для куба и других выпуклых полупрозрачных многогранников я бы посоветовал Вам следующий подход:

1. Включить отсечение задних граней (`glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)`, если у Вас `OpenGL`).
2. Нарисовать только задние грани (сначала - `glCullFace(GL_FRONT)`, потом - `RenderCube`).
3. Нарисовать только передние грани (сначала - `glCullFace(GL_BACK)`, потом опять `RenderCube`).

Comment: Кстати, если у Вас нет полупрозрачных граней, а альфа-канал дискретно прыгает от 0 до 1.0f, как на приведенном Вами примере, прекрасно сработает и просто включение Alpha test (в OpenGL это выглядит так: glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST); glAlphaFunc(GL_GEQUAL, 0.5); - это означает, что при значении альфы в текстуре от 0 до 0.5 ничего рисоваться не будет, в при 0.5-1.0 - нарисуется.) Блендинг как таковой в этом случае даже не нужен.