# Баг текстуры в Opengl

Tags: opengl

Когда я нахожусь по одну сторону от текстуры, она прозрачна и выглядит как нужно:

[image]

Но если я нахожусь с противоположной стороны от текстуры, с двумя ее сторонами что-то не так:

[image]

Текстура на всех гранях одна и та же.

Код загрузки текстур:

```
GLuint Render::loadTexture(const sf::String & name)
{
    sf::Image image;

    if (!image.loadFromFile(name))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    image.flipVertically();

    GLuint texture = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA, image.getSize().x, image.getSize().y, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.getPixelsPtr());
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, 0x812F);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, 0x812F);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    return texture;
}
```

Код отрисовки куба:

```
glTranslatef(x, y, z);


glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);   glVertex3f(-size, -size, -size);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0);   glVertex3f(size,  -size, -size);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1);   glVertex3f( size,  size, -size);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1);   glVertex3f( -size, size, -size);
glEnd();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(size, -size, size);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(-size,  -size, size);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f( -size,  size, size);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f( size, size, size);
glEnd();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[2]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(-size, -size,  size);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(-size, -size, -size);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(-size,  size, -size);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(-size,  size,  size);
glEnd();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[3]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(size, -size, -size);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(size,  -size, size);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(size,  size,  size);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(size, size,  -size);
glEnd();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[4]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(-size, -size,  size);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(size, -size, size);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f( size, -size, -size);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f( -size, -size,  -size);
glEnd();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[5]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(-size, size,  -size);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(size, size, -size);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f( size, size, size);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f( -size, size,  size);
glEnd();


glTranslatef(-x, -y, -z);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите код, которым вы накладываете текстуру и отрисовываете куб.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WJNeVQ7t - загрузка текстур.
http://pastebin.com/tAXAk0Rq - отрисовка куба

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблемы в обоих случаях - скрытые грани куба рисуются некорректно. Проверьте, что у Вас выставлен GL_ALPHA_TEST.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353210/rendering-glitch-with-gl-depth-test-and-transparent-textures

Кроме того, если альфа не дискретна 0/1, попробуйте такой подход:
[Порядок наложения текстур влияет на работу alpha-канала. Как это обойти?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/139823/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-alpha-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8)